# What does <> exactly do in a SQL self join?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new to SQL and I don't understand why you need a `<>` condition in a self join like below. I get that a join with an equal to condition won't return any results but I can't get my head around the need for `<>` in this case.

Please let me know if I need to provide any other info to answer this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.number AS num1,
    t2.number AS num2
FROM transportation_numbers t1
JOIN transportation_numbers t2 ON t1.index <> t2.index
WHERE
    t1.number < t2.number AND
    t1.number * t2.number > 11
```

Comment: <> is the standard SQL operator to check that the two operands are different, it's the opposite of = So in your query it says two different indexes will be taken.

Comment: A self join doesn't have to mean you need a not equals comparison (`<>`), sometimes it can be useful though. However, without more information about your specific problem we can't tell if your query is correct or not. A [mcve] would make things clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I've used it many times in things like self joins across one column that is not a unique identifier/key and then use the `<>` to prevent joining the same ID to itself.

Something like

```
SELECT a.id, 
    a.otherCol, 
    b.id, 
    b.otherCol
FROM T AS a INNER JOIN 
    T AS b ON b.someCol = a.someCol AND a.id <> b.id
```

Answer (score -2):

This means that each row in a table is joined to itself and every other row in that table.

```
SELECT
   A.LName AS Employee1
   ,B.LName AS Employee2
   ,A.City
FROM Employee A, Employee B
WHERE A.LName < B.LName
AND A.City = B.City
ORDER BY A.City;
```

Comment: Since 1992, there is a great thing named JOIN. You should wake up and use it, it's 2023 now.